# Swift Eureka form library - how do I customize a field after the form has rendered

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have a field that I would like to highlight after a validation error.  From looking at the documentation I'm not sure where I would customize it after the field has already been initialized.

Answer (score 4):

As there is yet no direct way to do validation, the easiest way is validate a row using the onChange() callback.

```
    <<< TextRow() {
           $0.title = "title"
        }.onChange{ row in
             if row.value?.containsString("error") == true {
                 row.cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
                 row.cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2
             }
        }
```

You can do any other customization there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer by @user3545708 but this is what official [example says](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift#L1183):

(default for all text rows, but you can change for each kind separately)

```
TextRow.defaultCellUpdate = { cell, row in
            if !row.isValid {
                cell.titleLabel?.textColor = .red
            }
        }
```